# python web scraping issues with mechanize

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to **scrape** web results from the website: https://promedmail.org/promed-posts/

I have followed beutifulsoup. mechanical soup and mechanize so far unable to **scrape** the search results.

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser,urlopen
browser = Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
browser.open("https://promedmail.org/promed-posts")
for form in browser.forms():
    if form.attrs['id'] == 'full_search':
        browser.form = form
        break
browser['search'] = 'US'
response = browser.submit()
content = response.read()
```

The content does not show the search results when typed in US. Any idea on what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention bs4 you can mimic the POST request the page makes. Extract the json item which contains the html the page would have been updated with (containing the results); parse that into BeautifulSoup object then reconstruct the results table as a dataframe:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

data = {
  'action': 'get_promed_search_content',
  'query[0][name]': 'kwby1',
  'query[0][value]': 'summary',
  'query[1][name]': 'search',
  'query[1][value]': 'US',
  'query[2][name]': 'date1',
#  'query[2][value]': '',
  'query[3][name]': 'date2',
#  'query[3][value]': '',
  'query[4][name]': 'feed_id',
  'query[4][value]': '1'
}

r = requests.post('https://promedmail.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', headers=headers, data=data).json()
soup = bs(r['results'], 'lxml')
df = pd.DataFrame([(i.find_next(text=True), 
                    i.a.text, 
                    f"https://promedmail.org/promed-post/?id={i.a['id'].replace('id','')}") for i in soup.select('li')]
                  , columns = ['Date', 'Title', 'Link'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked but I have still no idea how. Can you suggest any resources on its working?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-basics-82f8b5acd45c